# How to check if a file is empty or not?

Tags: fortran, fortran90

I have many files, before starting reading the files I want to check if the file is not empty.

Is there any way to check if a file is empty or not in Fortran 90?
Should I use INQUIRE?

Comment: Are you really using/limited to Fortran 90?  This is easy from Fortran 2003 on, which adds the SIZE= specifier to the INQUIRE statement.

Comment: I would put that as an answer, experience shows that most people write Fortran 90 here for any .f90 files they see.

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit hard to understand what you mean with 'not empty'. You have to distinguish between a few different scenarios:

1. The file doesn't exist.
2. The file exists, but can not be read. (Permissions not correct).
3. The file exists, but doesn't contain anything at all (which is what most people would describe as 'empty'.
4. The file exists, contains some data, but is incomplete.
5. The file exists and contains all data.

The most common approach if you have any worry at all that any of these options could happen is the heavy usage of the `iostat` parameter (and `iomsg` if your compiler understands Fortran 2003). If this parameter is given, the program will not crash if it fails to do a certain thing but set this variable to some non-zero integer.

See this example:

```
 program iotest
    implicit none
    integer :: ios
    character(len=100) :: iomsg
    integer :: iounit
    integer :: i, n
    character(len=*), parameter :: FILENAME='data.dat'

    open(newunit=iounit, file=FILENAME, action="READ", iostat=ios, iomsg=iomsg)
    call check(ios, iomsg, "OPEN")
    do i = 1, 10
        read(iounit, *, iostat=ios, iomsg=iomsg) n
        call check(ios, iomsg, "READ")
        print*, n
    end do
    close(iounit, iostat=ios, iomsg=iomsg)
    call check(ios, iomsg, "CLOSE")
contains
    subroutine check(ios, iomsg, op)
        implicit none
        integer, intent(in) :: ios
        character(len=*), intent(in) :: iomsg, op
        if (ios == 0) return   ! There was no error, continue
        print*, "Error encountered during " // trim(op)
        print*, "Error code: ", ios
        print*, "Error message: " // trim(iomsg)
        STOP 1
    end subroutine check
end program iotest
```

If you just need the size, you can try the `INQUIRE(file=FILENAME, size=iSize)` function. I say try, because I don't find any documentation about the `SIZE` keyword in any of my Fortran books, but testing after reading @IanH shows that it works. He thinks that it was added in Fortran 2003, but I don't find any reference to it in my Fortran 2003 handbook, so it might be 2008.

That said, he knows Fortran better than I do.

Comment: Actually, I was just referring to IanH. I don't know much about that and I therefore did not answer the question myself. I think Harald shouldn't have deleted his question. A simple edit was sufficient. Or a comment that I am wrong.

Comment: Oops, yes, the comment I was referring to was from @IanH, not you. Sorry.

Comment: Thank you so much for your kind help